# Matlab's griddata equivelent in python

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

In matlab there's the following griddata function [griddata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) which allows you to interpolate 2d points and it supports linear, nearest neighbor, natural neighbor, cubic and  Biharmonic spline interpolations.

In Python's scipy.interpolate there is a similar griddata function that supports only linear, cubic and nearest neighbor interpolations.

I need a function in python to interpolate using the natural neighbor and Biharmonic spline interpolations.

I found that old versions of matplotlib.mlab had a griddata fubction that supported natural neighbor interpolation, but they removed it for some reason.

Is there any Pytjon library that has a griddata function with natural neighbor and Biharmonic spline interpolations?

Comment: for Natural neighbor there is a python package https://pypi.org/project/naturalneighbor/

Comment: @KonarkK I also found this package but do you know if there is a similar package for 2d? I know I can use the 3D interpolation on 2d data but this would be slower. They claim in the page that "There are several implementations of 2D natural neighbor interpolation in Python" but I didn't find any.